# Can nodes be added to an HBox during runtime?

Tags: javafx, dynamic, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application in which displays information that is received from a node.js server. At one point, when it receives a specific string "new_game", it should reload 4 VBoxes which are inside of an HBox. Is it possible to remove the old VBoxes and put in new ones after the program has already launched?

(FYI, I am asking this because updating the VBoxes would be kind of a hassle because of my nooby code.)

Comment: The short answer is yes you can. This is actually a quite normal procedure.

Comment: By the way xou wrote it i deduct it's done by using HBox.getchildren().add(nodes). But if i get the Information in a loop in my main, how do i change the hbox object, which is inside the @Override start method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to remove the old vBoxes and add new one's I would use some of this:

```
hBox.getChildren().clear();
```

would remove everthing of this hbox so if you only want to remove the 4 specific vboxes then use this:

```
hBox.getChildren().remove(vBox1, vBox2, vBox3, vBox4);
```

then you want to add the new vboxes, do it like this

```
hBox.getChildren().addAll(newVBox1, newVBox2, newVBox3, newVBox4);
```

I hope this answers your question